# How to inherit context correctly when using yarn workspaces and react-router-dom v6?

Tags: react-router, react-router-dom, react-context, yarn-workspaces

I have a monorepo using yarn workspaces and lerna. The structure of my app is basically a 'hub' for importing other yarn packages, and what I'd like to be able to do is allow each package that is being imported to define their own `Routes`. This works fine if the components are imported from the same package, but when they're imported from other yarn packages, the react router context is lost.

I believe the problem is that both packages are imported separate instances of react-router, so the context for `Router` is not being passed down from the parent to child components. It seems [similar to this issue with React context](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/13991#issuecomment-435587809), but I'm not sure if there's a workaround or other suggested way to fix this issue with react router v6.

A simplified example of what I'm trying to achieve is:

```
// ImportedApp.js
function ImportedApp() {
    return (
        <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<div>Root of app</div>} />
            <Route path="testSubSection" element={<div>Sub page of app</div>} />
        </Routes >
    );
}

// App.js
import ImportedApp from 'ImportedApp';

function AppRoutes() {
    return (
        <Routes>
            <Route
                path="/importedApp/*"
                element={
                      <ImportedApp />
                }
            <Route
                path="/"
                element={<div>My App</div>}
            />
        </Routes>
    );
}
```

In the above example, if ImportedApp.js is in the same package as App.js, there are no problems. But if I have the exact same code and import it from a separate yarn package, I get

```
Uncaught Error: useRoutes() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component.
```

I've tried a combination of using `alias` and `nohoist` in my `package.json` but so far nothing is helping me achieve the goal of getting both to share the same library reference.

Answer (score 1):

The fix here was two fold-

First, an alias for both `react-router` and `react-router-dom` needed to be added. But the trick was, this alias needed to be added to *both* the parent and inherited package.

So the `parent-package` webpack file eventually looks like:

```
resolve: {
        alias: {
            'react-router-dom': join(__dirname, '..', 'node_modules', 'react-router-dom', '/'),
            'react-router': join(__dirname, '..', 'node_modules', 'react-router', '/'),
        },
        extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.jsx', '.less', '.css'],
    },
```

and the inherited package:

```
resolve: {
        alias: {
            'react-router-dom': join(
                __dirname,
                '..',
                '..',
                'parent-package',
                'node_modules',
                'react-router-dom',
                '/',
            ),
            'react-router': join(
                __dirname,
                '..',
                '..',
                'parent-package',
                'node_modules',
                'react-router',
                '/',
            ),
        },
    },
```